# DC.js, D3.js | How to remove animation from postRender?

Tags: d3.js, dc.js

I'm using postRender to change the x position of some y axis labels in a couple of DC charts:

```
function moveLabels() {

  var obj = d3.selectAll('text.y-axis-label');

  for (var i=0; i<obj[0].length; i++) {
    var t = d3.transform(d3.select(obj[0][i]).attr("transform"));
    var keepY = t.translate[1];
    d3.select(obj[0][i]).attr("transform","translate(18,"+keepY+") rotate(-90)");
  }

}
```

It works fine, but there's an animation applied to the move. Every time I change a dropdown and redraw the chart, the y axis label slides around. Does anyone know how to get rid of it? I've tried:

```
d3.select(obj[0][i]).transition().attr("delay","0").attr("transform","translate(18,"+keepY+") rotate(-90)");
```

and

```
d3.select(obj[0][i]).transition().attr("duration","0").attr("transform","translate(18,"+keepY+") rotate(-90)");
```

Comment: I think you may want to use the `pretransition` event for this instead of `postRender` - the former is before the transitions start and the latter is after. Also `pretransition` will fire for both renders and redraws (`renderlet` is the equivalent post-transition). It's even possible to change both the origin and destination of transitions in `pretransition`. (I can dig up an example if you're interested.)

Comment: Thanks for your comment but `pretransition` doesn't seem to fire at all. Do you know of a list of these event types anywhere?

Comment: [Here's the doc.](http://dc-js.github.io/dc.js/docs/html/dc.baseMixin.html#on) Maybe you are using an old version of dc.js? This has been around since one of the 2.0 betas.